# Enable scroll onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with 2 divs, the first div should fill the whole screen (width & height) and once there is a button or link clicked in it, it should enable the scroll besides take to the second div.

I have been able to set something like this https://codepen.io/malditojavi/project/editor/ZgWYrZ/#0 But I'm unable to change the class of the  with my own class 'allowscrolling' that would re-enable that scroll.

I used this function

```
allowScrolling() {
    document.getElementByTagName("body").className = "allowscrolling";
}
```

Also tried via jquery, with:

```
<script>
 $("button").click(function(){
 $("body").css("overflow","scroll");
 });
</script>
```

But both won't enable scroll after I click the first link. Anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `getElementByTagName` that returns a single element. There is a `getElementsByTagName` that returns an array. Use that and get the first element of the arrray to set the class

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'allowscrolling';`

Comment: Did that change https://codepen.io/malditojavi/project/editor/ZgWYrZ/ still not able to scroll.

Comment: it's `getElementsByTagName` notice the `s` in `getElements`

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className += ' allowscrolling';`

This will do, you can't use jQuery if you don't load it in your project.